# How to detect that the AlphaMaskFilter is completely gone in easeljs/createjs

Tags: html, createjs, easeljs

I am doing a little scratch/reveal game based on the AlphaMaskFilter example:
http://createjs.com/demos/easeljs/AlphaMaskReveal.html

I want to detect that the the mask is completely gone, or use a threshold (90% scratched for example).

I read the doc on AlphaMaskFilter, shape and graphics objects and im not really sure how to achieve this.

Im not even sure i Have acess to the pixel information and check the alpha channel to detect it, but even so, I wonder if I will performance issue.

any help is welcome, thanks.

**** EDIT **** ADD TO THE ACCEPTED ANSWER ****

So, I was able to have the pct of transparency using the AlphaMapFilter (thanks Lanny). 
The AlphaMapFilter offer you a mapping to the alpha channel of all the pixels.
Here is a little sample code that worked for me:

```
        // mShapeToScratch is a createjs Shape. like in the http://createjs.com/demos/easeljs/AlphaMaskReveal.html example
        var alphaMaskFilter = new createjs.AlphaMapFilter(mShapeToScratch.cacheCanvas);
        var canvas = alphaMaskFilter.alphaMap;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var alphaData = imgData.data;
        var pixelTotal = rect.h*rect.w;
        var transparentPixel = 0;

        // rect.h is the height of the image and rect.w is the width not shown in the example
        for (var y = 0; y < rect.h; ++y)
        {
          for (var x=0; x < rect.w; ++x)
          {
            var pixelIdx = (y*rect.w + x);

            if(alphaData[pixelIdx] > 128) // transparent will be 255.
            {
                transparentPixel++;
            }
        }

        console.log("transparent % = " + transparentPixel/pixelTotal);
```

This example checks all the pixels, but it's pretty easy to check one every X pixels to speeds up checks as Lanny suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alpha mask uses canvas composite operation, and not pixel access, so without some completely custom approach, there isn't a great way to do this.

Iterating pixels (check out AlphaMapFilter as an example) would work - but could be fairly slow. Maybe checking every 4th, 10th, or 25th pixel would speed it up.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Lanny, if I understand correctly, you are saying that 
A) There is no easy way to detect the amount of reveal with the AlphaMaskFilter.
and
B) if I want to use the pixel check solution, i can't go with the AlphaMaskFilter, I should use the AlphaMapFilter instead.

Did I understand correclty ?

Comment: Sort of. AlphaMapFilter uses a specific channel, so you can provide a compressed JPG as the mask. You would have to make a custom filter that uses the AlphaMapFilter approach (checking pixels), change it to check the alpha instead, and then implement some sort of coverage algorithm.